# For data in a table from a function in Vue.js and Vuetify.js

Tags: javascript, html, css, vue.js, vuetify.js

I'm trying to output a table, but it's printing just one row. How can i fix it? I've tried different things (Vanilla JS worked). It's for study purposes and i'm kinda new in JS and Vue.js in general.
This is the table:

```
                                  <template>
                                    <v-data-table
                                      :headers="headers"
                                      :items="houses"
                                      class="elevation-1"
                                    >
                                      <template v-slot:items="data">
                                        <td class="text-xs-left">{{ data.item.name }}</td>
                                        <td class="text-xs-left">{{ data.item.party }}</td>
                                        <td class="text-xs-left">{{ data.item.state }}</td>
                                        <td class="text-xs-left">{{ data.item.seniority }}</td>
                                        <td class="text-xs-left">{{ data.item.votes }}</td>
                                      </template>
                                    </v-data-table>
                                  </template>
```

This is the header:

```
                  headers: [
                    { text: 'Full Name', value: 'name' },
                    { text: 'Party', value: 'party' },
                    { text: 'State', value: 'state' },
                    { text: 'Seniority', value: 'seniority' },
                    { text: '% Votes', value: 'votes' }
                  ],
                  houses: [
                  {
                      name: getNameHouse(),
                      party: getPartyHouse(),
                      state: getStateHouse(),
                      seniority: getSeniorityHouse(),
                      votes: getVoteHouse()
                    },
                  ]
```

This is the header:

```
function getPartyHouse (){
var JSONhouse = data_house,
jHouseLen = JSONhouse.results[0].num_results;

for (var i = 0; i < jHouseLen; i ++ ){
    return JSONhouse.results[0].members[i].party;
}
```

}
This is the sample of the function that is called, and every other function is similar.

[What i see](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y2vSc.png)

Comment: From what I can tell, the object containing your data, `houses`, is an array of objects with a length of 1. This means that your table will only end up printing 1 row containing the data that you provided. I'd recommend building your full set of data prior to creating the table.

Answer (score 0):

From my comment:

> From what I can tell, the object containing your data, houses, is an array of objects with a length of 1. This means that your table will only end up printing 1 row containing the data that you provided. I'd recommend building your full set of data prior to creating the table.

Here's a an example that may help clarify what I was attempting to convey in my comment. Note that it's not perfect and may need to be modified depending on the structure of your input.

```js
data: () => {
  return {
    headers: [{
      text: 'Full Name',
      value: 'name'
    }, {
      text: 'Party',
      value: 'party'
    }, {
      text: 'State',
      value: 'state'
    }, {
      text: 'Seniority',
      value: 'seniority'
    }, {
      text: '% Votes',
      value: 'votes'
    }],
    // Only initialize the container for our data,
    // it will be populated once the component is created
    houses: []
  }
},
created: () => {
  // Get the data that we want to pull our houses from
  let input = data_house.results[0].members
  
  // Loop through our data
  input.forEach((member) => {
    // At each iteration, pull the relevent data and append it to our houses array
    houses.push({
      name: member.name,
      party: member.party,
      state: member.state,
      seniority: member.seniority,
      votes: member.votes,
    })
  })
}
```

```html
<v-data-table :headers="headers" :items="houses" class="elevation-1">
  <template v-slot:items="data">
    <td class="text-xs-left">{{ data.item.name }}</td>
    <td class="text-xs-left">{{ data.item.party }}</td>
    <td class="text-xs-left">{{ data.item.state }}</td>
    <td class="text-xs-left">{{ data.item.seniority }}</td>
    <td class="text-xs-left">{{ data.item.votes }}</td>
  </template>
</v-data-table>
```